# How to execute only particular part of the scikit-learn pipeline?

Tags: python, python-3.x, machine-learning, scikit-learn, pipeline

*Below is part of the code that is relevant to the question. If there is a need for full code, here is a full reproducible code that downloads data too: https://github.com/ageron/handson-ml2/blob/master/02_end_to_end_machine_learning_project.ipynb*

I have a pipeline:

```py
prepare_select_and_predict_pipeline = Pipeline([
    ('preparation', full_pipeline),
    ('feature_selection', TopFeatureSelector(feature_importances, k)),
    ('svm_reg', SVR(**rnd_search.best_params_))
])
```

Now, I want to execute only this part from the pipeline above:

```py
('preparation', full_pipeline),
('feature_selection', TopFeatureSelector(feature_importances, k)),
```

I tried `prepare_select_and_predict_pipeline.fit(housing, housing_labels)`, but it executes the SVM part too.

In the end I need to get the same result from the above pipeline as I execute code below:

```py
preparation_and_feature_selection_pipeline = Pipeline([
    ('preparation', full_pipeline),
    ('feature_selection', TopFeatureSelector(feature_importances, k))
])

housing_prepared_top_k_features = preparation_and_feature_selection_pipeline.fit_transform(housing)
```

How I can do that?

Comment: Any strong reason to not have both declarations? I mean, one pipeline with 2 steps and another one with 3 steps.

Comment: @HemersonTacon To not repeat same code again and if possible have one place for modifications.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`FeatureUnion` can do the trick:

```
from sklearn.pipeline import FeatureUnion, Pipeline

prepare_select_pipeline = Pipeline([
    ('preparation', full_pipeline),
    ('feature_selection', TopFeatureSelector(feature_importances, k))
])

feats = FeatureUnion([('prepare_and_select', prepare_select_pipeline)])

prepare_select_and_predict_pipeline = Pipeline([('feats', feats),
                               ('svm_reg', SVR(**rnd_search.best_params_))])
```

You can find more information about this in [A Deep Dive Into Sklearn Pipelines](https://www.kaggle.com/baghern/a-deep-dive-into-sklearn-pipelines)

Comment: So if I understand correctly here we are creating first pipeline and after creating second pipeline based on first by adding additional transformer. Am I understand it correct?

Comment: Yes. In this way, you can achieve what you wanted (no code duplication and only one point of change for possible modifications).

Comment: Do you need FeatureUnion here?  Won't it be the same to use the `prepare_select_pipeline` as the first step in the larger pipeline?

Comment: You can definitely do it simpler in the way you state in your answer for sure (indexing the pipeline). However, one advantage that I see with the `FeatureUnion` is that it keeps the readability and manageability of the code because you will not have some magic indexes being accessed without knowing right away which part of the pipeline is being executed, and you would avoid completely miss-indexing. Of course that with a small pipeline this advantage is negligible, but with bigger pipelines this can make quite a difference.

Comment: I mean, without slicing, your code would work just as well replacing `feats` in your last pipeline with `prepare_select_pipeline`. I don't see how the `FeatureUnion` is helping anything?

Answer (score 5):

You can slice pipelines as though they were lists (version >=0.21), so

```py
prepare_select_and_predict_pipeline[:-1].fit_transform(housing)
```

should work.

(You need to be careful here; you are *refitting* the transformer parts of the pipeline, so doing it on a new dataset followed by `prepare_select_and_predict_pipeline.predict(X_new)` will be using the refitted transformers!  You could `clone` to a new variable if needed.)